# overriding html form input validation

Tags: php, html, validation, forms

I am a beginner in html/php

I wonder why html form input validation (required) not working for input like `<myText>`.ie input inside < and >

No data is received in my php page.

How can i solve this problem

index.html

```
<form action="genPdf.php" method="POST">

    <input  type="text" name="text" required="required" ></input>
    <input type="submit"  value="Click"></input>
</form>
```

genPdf.php

```
<?php
$data=$_POST["text"];
echo $data;
?>
```

How to avoid this situation

Thanks in advance

please do help

Comment: required="required"  done but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function validate ($ci){
$ci= htmlspecialchars($ci);
}

$data=validate($_POST["text"]);
echo $data;

?>
```

Use this bit of code and everything will work fine , you need to encode the any codes that are in "<" .

Answer (score 0):

make `required = "required"`. and also correct your input type, it should be `type="text"` like-

```
<input  type="text" name="name"  required="required" ></input>
```

and in your genPdf.php file receive the value like-

```
<?php
$data=$_POST["name"];
echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

its working dude just add both files in xampp pannel's htdocs folder and type localhost in browser den u will see that your file is der den click on dem and type some words in text box then it will through yuor output....gudluck